# UIWebview load ppt and doc crash app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I need to load doc and ppt files in `UIWebView`.
I have 2 different `UIWebView` in one controller.

```
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"doc"]]]];
[self.webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ppt" ofType:@"ppt"]]]];
```

This crash the app:

```
OfficeImport`WrdEshBackground::takeClientData(WrdEshClientData*):
0x34c4fe3c:  str.w  r1, [r0, #224] //on this line
```

But If I load files with the same format:

```
[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ppt" ofType:@"ppt"]]]];
[self.webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ppt" ofType:@"ppt"]]]];
```

It work well.

If I wait when `UIWebView` finished load first request, then start second it works well.
But I need to load a lot of files in tableView. `UITableViewCel` will contain `UIWebView` that load this files.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a way which i had used to show data into webView using NSData object with MIME type, I have convert my file into NSData object and display like

```
if ([docType isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
    [webView loadData:documentDataObject MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
} else if ([docType isEqualToString:@"doc"]) {
    [webView loadData:documentDataObject MIMEType:@"application/msword" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
} else if ([docType isEqualToString:@"docx"]) {
    [webView loadData:documentDataObject MIMEType:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
} else if ([docType isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
    [webView loadData:documentDataObject MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
} else if ([docType isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
    [webView loadData:documentDataObject MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

Comment: I try your code but it doesn't help. `NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"doc" ofType:@"doc"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
    [self.webview loadData:myData MIMEType:@"application/msword" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    [self.webview1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ppt" ofType:@"ppt"]]]];` This error
OfficeImport`WrdEshReader::readClientAnchor(EshContentBase&, EshHeader const&): 0x34bc79b8:  str.w  r4, [r0, #348]

Comment: i guess there is a problem with your doc file, try with another file

Comment: There aren't problem in doc file, if I try to load it in both `webview` it work well, but if different types of file on one thread in different webview it crashes the app

Comment: it sounds strange, why dont you create 2 thread and load them separately